# Improve the placement of the "you need 150 reputation" banner in the election

Tags: feature-request, election, responsive-design

I know I'm not eligible to vote in the election at The Workplace. But it stuck me as odd that I wasn't warned about that when I tried to do so. Well, it turned out I was wrong, but the banner was placed rather unlucky for mobile devices: [image]

**Can we place the banner closer to the voting buttons**, at least on small screen widths such as mobile devices.